# How to debug my server hard drive I/O issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a small headless server on my LAN running Ubuntu 20.04.  Recently I had an issue where one of my external drives was intermittently going into read-only mode and sometimes failing to mount at all after a restart. This being an older mechanical drive, my assumption was that it was on the way out.  I then bought a new Crucial MX500 4TB internal drive, installed it and began to rsync the data.

Around 60GB into the process the internal drive began to exhibit some I/O errors. Here are a few snippets from the syslog:

```
Nov 15 20:46:33 hm80 kernel: [ 1138.328403] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov 15 20:46:33 hm80 kernel: [ 1138.328409] ata3.00: cmd 61/e8:00:08:0f:04/08:00:52:01:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 1167360 ou
Nov 15 20:46:33 hm80 kernel: [ 1138.328409]          res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)

Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798072] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=98s
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798084] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 4c 03 d9 00 00 00 09 c8 00 00
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798090] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1275320576 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 44 prio class 2
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798105] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 10 writing to inode 179055013 starting block 159415072)
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798123] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 10 writing to inode 179055014 starting block 159415080)

Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798250] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=98s
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798252] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 159414816
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798257] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#19 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 4c 03 d2 d0 00 00 06 20 00 00
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798264] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1275318992 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 29 prio class 2
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798286] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 159414817
Nov 15 20:47:42 hm80 kernel: [ 1206.798296] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 159414818
```

After a reboot all seemed to be ok and I resumed the sync.  Everything went fine.  The same drive is also host to a handful of backups sync'd from other servers.  That job runs overnight.  Today after 12 hours of rsync'ing, the machine became close to unresponsive and had only managed to d/l approx 400GB.  Looking at the rsync output it looked again to be writing very slow.  Then some really odd stuff started happening like I could no longer ssh into the server and basic commands like `ls` would hang.

I've opened the computer, checked cable connections and on reboot, the computer actually went to GRUB which I've never seen it do before. Now it is running the same rsync routine and everything again seems to be fine.

Since this all comes in response to another external drive having similar issues I'm considering the following possibilities:

- Purely by coincidence, I got a bad drive.  Return it and try again.
- Something is wrong with the drive controller or the computer itself (which may have caused the original issues I had with my first drive)
- Bad SATA cable?

How can I debug an issue like this when it is intermittent? Is there anything to be gleaned from those syslog entries that could point to where, specifically, things are going awry?

**UPDATE:**

```
$ e2fsck -c /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
/dev/sdb1: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdb1: 4281238/244195328 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 561744117/976754176 blocks
```

```
$ smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.2.0-36-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     CT4000MX500SSD1
Serial Number:    2320E6D55BEE
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 1e6d55bee
Firmware Version: M3CR046
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Nov 16 19:30:08 2023 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  30) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0031) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       14
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       262
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   068   057   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 25/43)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4615089440
247 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37591628
248 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11026271

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Completed [00% left] (0-65535)
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: @FrankThomas - The original drive I had issues with was USB. The new drive is internal SATA.

Comment: ahh ok, i hadn't realized you had installed the new disk as an internal. assuming you have enough power from the power supply, I'd check the SMART stats on the disk, and see if it reports healthy. I usually like to do a full disk scan on a new disk to ensure that it interacts with every sector, so I can be sure that all the SMART stats are accurate and nothing is hiding. you can use `e2fsck` to invoke badblocks to test the disks entire surface with `e2fsck -c`. if afterward you have read/write errors or pending/reallocated/uncorrectable sectors, send it back.

Comment: Thanks Frank - I did run `smartctl` on it when I installed and again just now.  Basic health check says `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`.  I will run the badblocks check and report back in a few hours.

Comment: I've had dead/dying drives "pass" SMART summaries, so be sure to look at the actual statistics, not just the one-liner "PASSED" result. If you have gnome, i believe the Gnome Disks applet will display the individual results.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I added output of `e2fsck` and `smartctl -a`.  I see there is a `-x` option which shows even more data.  At the moment I don't see anything alarming.

Comment: yeah looks great to me. unfourtunatly that means that either your issue was a fluke, and you just wait until you are comfortable it won't recur, or it means that just about any component of your PC could be responsible; CPU, RAM, Mobo, PS, OS corruption, etc. vid card is about the only thing that doesn't play a role.

Comment: @FrankThomas - just thought I would follow up here to say that my daily rsync has run for the last two days as well as a ton of other I/O and everything appears to be stable.  It's all a bit weird and for me, a first - a drive that screws everything up through three reboots and then mysteriously settles down and behaves perfectly normally.  I suppose time will tell but I'm mystified at this point.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with that drive in Debian.